# How to confirm if ES6 is being used (ReactJS + Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have the following set up:

[image]

And I am trying to do the following:

```
case 'UPDATE_PASSWORD':
  return {
    ...state, //preserve current state, apply changes to it below
    password: action.password,
  };
```

but I am getting:

`Unexpected token (5:8)` at where '...' starts

What may be the issue? How do I check if I am using ES6?

Comment: That's neither ES5 or ES6, that's a draft proposal, so you'd need to enable https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: Show your babel settings

Comment: Please consider marking your question answered or editing it if you need more information!

Answer (score 6):

This is a proposed ECMAScript feature (object spread) and can be enabled by adding `stage-0` to your babel presets:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

Then, in your `.babelrc` or within your `webpack.config.js` query add the preset to your babel settings. Example `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react",
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

Or, if you make use of the webpack `babel-loader` query string:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Babel presets are an assortment of many transformations. As per zerkms' suggestion, you could use `stage-2`, which does not include/transpile many other features you may not be using at this time. If you really *just* want the object spread to work, you can also just install [transform object rest spread](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

Comment: FYI ES7 is done, spread isn't part of it: http://www.2ality.com/2016/01/ecmascript-2016.html

Comment: Interesting, any info on whether it will be part of ES8 or what replaces it?

Comment: `stage-0` is *slightly* too much for it, `stage-2` would be just fine.

Comment: Technically, including `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` would be enough. However, unless you really want to optimize your dependencies, I would suggest adding `stage-0` and no longer worry about any of the latest features.

Comment: It is mad to add `stage-0`. "no longer worry about any of the latest features" --- about probable and sometimes unlikely to be standardised ever features.